# Replacing the gimble in a drone controller

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi, signal

as far as I understand that drone controller for a DJI phantom pro has some sort of gimble the controls the direction of the drone. I'm trying to replace that gimble and control  the drone via a Raspberry Pi and I would like to confirm that the signal that coming out of the gimble is a Digital signal not analog. Is that true? Your help is very much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: ’Twas brillig, and the slithy toves 
      Did gyre and gimble in the wabe: 
All mimsy were the borogoves, 
      And the mome raths outgrabe.

Comment: What @SpehroPefhany is trying to convey (in a very poetic way), is that it is completely unclear what you are talking about and what you want to achieve. For example, what is a “gimble”? I know of a gimbal but that is a mechanical device that controls where the drone’s camera is pointed and cannot be used to control the drone. Where does a RaspberryPi come into it?

Comment: Jabberwocky aside, do you perhaps mean "IMU" or "gyroscope" when you say "gimble"?

Comment: Sorry all for the confusion. Yes i actually mean a gyroscope. Specifically, the gimble joystick on the controller as the one in this link : https://www.racedayquads.com/products/frsky-m9-high-sensitivity-hall-sensor-for-x9d-x9d-plus?variant=42275743507&gclid=CjwKCAiAkan9BRAqEiwAP9X6UVsv8PlElrEcLoiAMVUKo26qDCRzSfbWtvL_GFV4_TJUhd-Lx3z4DRoCnMoQAvD_BwE.

Comment: Also, the thing i'm trying to do is instead of sending a signal via this gimble joystick, I want to send it via a Pi. And answering "StarCat", the gimble joystick control not only the camera I think, but mainly controls the moment of the drone as in this link https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+fly+a+dji+phantom+4&oq=how+to+fly+a+dji+phantom+4+&aqs=chrome..69i57.9890j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_msqyX6rXCq2O9PwPup6T6Ak16. Thanks!